# Conceal specific function from base class in derived class interface

Tags: c++, using, virtual-inheritance

```
struct IA 
{
    virtual void Init() = 0;
    .....
};

struct A : public IA
{
    void Init() {};
    .....
};

struct B : public A
{
    int Init() { return 1; };
};
```

With such design i got  *error C2555: 'B::Init': overriding virtual function return type ...*

Can i somehow conceal Init() from A, i don't want to conceal other A's functions. Class A used from other places as A class not only through B class.

EDIT: I need to have two Init functions in the hierarchy with only difference in return types. 
I don't need A::Init to be called on objects of B type.
Actually i can do it by

```
struct B : private A
{
    using A::.... // all, except Init
    int Init() { return 1; };
};
```

But there are a big lot of functions in A:(

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Maybe your `Init` function shouldn't be virtual.

Comment: @Brian Bi, you can put it as an answer and  will up it. But, now it is intresting for me as for fun. So any other answers are appreciated.

Comment: what means conceal? you don't want it to be visible outside or just avoid error?

Answer (score 1):

Due to inheritance, your `struct B` contains both the function signatures `void Init();` and
`int Init();` and C++ does not allow overloading methods which differ only in their return types.

Possible inelegant solutions:

- You can fix this error by declaring your the `void Init();` method in `struct A` as private and keeping the rest of the methods that you would like to inherit as public.
- Another fix would be to add a dummy parameter such as `bool` and call the method with `Init(true)`. Note that you cannot define a default value for this dummy parameter, else you would end up with the same error.